# Prison ships in The Ultimate Gamble

Tags: star-wars

In *The Ultimate Gamble* (Marvel Star Wars issue #19, 1978/1979), we see prison ships capable of ferrying 100,000+ prisoners at once, as shown in the picture below (courtesy of Wookieepedia):

[image: The prison ships]

What class(es) are these ships from?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_prison_barge

Comment: Class unknown. Probably just some reconditioned Venator-class Star Destroyers by the looks of them.

Comment: That picture would suggest that, if reconditioned Venators were used, they were reconditioned by different shipyards, but both reconditions shown here entailed the filling out of the aft notches, expanding the conning tower aftward, as well as the gutting of hangar bays, leaving only the ventral hangar at most. Plus you just quoted the source of the very picture I posted.

Comment: If you read "Tarkin", you'll find that they mention all sorts of weird/wonderful mashup ships made of leftover crap from the clone wars.

Comment: I might also suggest that if you plan to quote from a specific source like wookieepedia, that you should mention that you've done so.

Comment: One would think that a reconditioned Venator capable of housing 100k prisoners would be a minimum-security prison ship devoid of any proper rehab facility: higher-security prisons tend to take up more space per inmate in the absence of rehabilitation facilities (these would be planetside).